# When post with jQuery, received JSON model with incorrect spelling

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET Core and now trying to use post with jQuery.
The situation I encounter was like this:

I have a model

```
public class Model {
    int INT_VALUE { get; set; }
    string STR_VALUE { get; set; }
    int SOME { get; set; }
}
```

and an API like

```
[HttpPost]
public Model GetValues(string val) {
    Model m = new Model { INT_VALUE = 1, STR_VALUE = "hi", SOME = "there" };
    return m;
}
```

Now I request with post using jQuery

```
$.post('api/GetValues', { val: "abc" })
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        if (data.INT_VALUE === 1) {
            console.log("Hit!");
        }
    });
```

The point is that if I get Model with INT_VALUE === 1 log **'Hit!'**
but it did not work. (did not get in `console.log("Hit!")`)

So, I check the receiving json value then I found strange values with wrong spelling like

```
{"inT_VALUE":1,"stR_VALUE":"hi","some":"there"}
```

What I expected is

```
{"INT_VALUE":1,"STR_VALUE":"hi","SOME":"there"}
```

or

```
{"int_value":1,"str_value":"hi","some":"there"}
```

Is there any way to change spelling which I can expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could change to use PascalCase for properties of your model (ex: IntValue, StrValue...).  Then you could force Json Serializer to use PascalCase by following setting.

In your Startup.cs file, find your ConfigureServices method and update it like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
}
```

Then in client side, you could access property using the same name as defined in your model (IntValue, StrValue...).